# Continue python script even after error ocurred

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a Python script that logs temperature in my room and use requests library to send the data. Sometimes I lose wifi signal and the script stops completely after an error with the requests.

```
import sys
import time
import Adafruit_DHT
import requests

raspid = 1
sensor = 11
pin = 25

while True:   
    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)
    if humidity is not None and temperature is not None:
        datos = {'temperatura': 'temperature', 'humedad': 'humidity', 'raspid': 'raspid'}
        r = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", data=datos)
        print(r.text)
    else:
        print ('Error de lectura!')
        time.sleep(15)
```

Error when disconnected from wifi

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/dht11 request post.py", line 19, in <module>
    r = requests.post("http://mehr.cl/link.php", data=datos)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 94, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 49, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 457, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 569, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 407, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(101, 'Network is unreachable'))
>>>
```

Is there a way to ignore the error and just try again?

Comment: Use a [`try-except`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) statement.

Comment: Just put exception handler around your `post` line.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is. It's precisely trying, and catching any error raised.

Here is basically how it works:

```
try:
    # Some action that could raise an error

except:
    # What to do when an error occurs
```

For deeper explanation, check the documentation: [Errors and Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/errors.html).

There are several built-in exceptions, among which, `ConnectionError`. If you know the exact exception you're expecting, then you must add it to the `except` clause:

```
try:
    # Actions that might raise a ConnectionError

except ConnectionError:
    # Process the error, for instance, try again
```

Comment: Maybe specifically except ConnectionError:

Comment: ConnectionError is not defined in Python27, the version the OP is using.

Comment: @Tnerual and you can tell that how?

Comment: @OmidCompSCI Check the traceback ;)

Comment: @Tnerual Still, the traceback looks like `ConnectionError` is defined. At least in Python 3, if the exception is not a built-in, the traceback prefixes it by the module name, and vice-versa

Comment: @Rightleg. This does not mean that it can be used from the working code, doesn't it ?

Comment: Rather than treat all exceptions equally, if the calling code really doesnt know **ConnectionError** class it could test **"ConnectionError" in str(exc)**.  Hacky, but unqualified exception catching consistently bites you.

Comment: But he could also **from requests import ConnectionError** that would be cleaner.  And consider a sleep or something to wait till wifi is back, it would loop quickly otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to use a [try-except](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) statement. As follows

```
while True:
    try:
        #action which may create an error
    except Exception as exc:
        print('[!!!] {err}'.format(err=exc))
        #action to perform: Nothing in your case
```

Note that a good practice is that an error [should never pass silently](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

---

Following the discussion in comments, note also that if you use `Exception` to handle your error, you will still be able to stop the `while`-loop manually, since you use python27.

Comment: Speaking of good practice, `Exception` should not be caught, because it includes `KeyboardInterrupt`. If the latter is caught and treated as a normal exception, you will not be able to stop the execution manually.

Comment: @Rightleg. Good to know. Which PEP ? I would have said that it appears good to be able to stop the code manually. Don't you think so ?

Comment: I can't think of a PEP, but it's rather logical. I can't see any situation where you don't want your program to be interruptable by the keyboard... Although such situations _might_ happen, it's still unlikely. Besides, catching `KeyboardInterrupt` precisely makes you unable to stop your program manually, because it will *take the execution flow into the `except` clause*, and the program will keep on running from the `except` clause's end, while you want to *stop the execution flow*.

Comment: @Rightleg. Ah ok so we say the same thing. I should have read you first comment better. But you too. KeyboardInterrupt is not (anymore?) caught via `Exception` in Python27. I.e. not included in `Exception`.

Comment: +1 for `except Exception`. `KeyboardInterrupt` subclasses BaseException, not Exception, contrary to the first comment

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your loop inside a *try* statement.

```
while True:  
    try: 
        humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)
        if humidity is not None and temperature is not None:
            datos = {'temperatura': 'temperature', 'humedad': 'humidity', 'raspid': 'raspid'}
            r = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", data=datos)
            print(r.text)
        else:
            print ('Error de lectura!')
            time.sleep(15)
            sys.exit(1)
    except ConnectionError:
      continue
```

By doing so your code will escape the error, and thus preventing it to stop, whenever you lose your connection.